# Pass variable in remote SSH-command in Jenkins-job

Tags: ssh, bash, shell, jenkins, environment-variables

i have a little test job:

```
touch 22.txt
echo "wwe" > 22.txt
test=$(echo ${BUILD_NUMBER})
echo $test
ssh jenkins@srv1 "mkdir D:\myfolder\$test"
ssh jenkins@srv1 "dir D:\myfolder\"
```

`BUILD_NUMBER` means build number of job in Jenkins 
What i have in output:

```
Running as SYSTEM
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on MAC-slave in workspace /Users/Admin/workspace/testmacosx
[testmacosx] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/folders/rq/4q3q1m2959q6zpgxghhrvdnw0000gn/T/jenkins1551827609931995498.sh
+ touch 22.txt
+ echo wwe
++ echo 5
+ test=5
+ echo 5
5
+ ssh jenkins@srv1 'mkdir D:\myfolder$test'
/var/folders/rq/4q3q1m2959q6zpgxghhrvdnw0000gn/T/jenkins1551827609931995498.sh: line 7: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

How, you have saw, it does not see this variable `$test` in the remote ssh-command. How i can pass this variable ? Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved.
Via this:
`ssh jenkins@srv1 "mkdir D:\myfolder\\$test"`
So, we have to add `\` before our variable

Comment: Worked for me today